# SELECIONAR JSON NODEJS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Então tenho o seguinte JSON :

```
var json = {
  'cache-control': 'no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0',
  'content-length': '12747',
  'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
  'content-language': 'pt-br',
  'set-cookie': [
    'ApplicationGatewayAffinity05CORS=97a3c470e904c1e72a708e84142b5859; Path=/; SameSite=None; Secure',
    'ApplicationGatewayAffinity05=97a3c470e904c1e72a708e84142b5859; Path=/']
}
```

Como faço pra selecionar o set-cookie? Tentei o var cookie = json.set-cookie mas não funciona.

Comment: `json['set-cookie']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atributos de um Objeto literal (JSON) podem ser acessados como chaves em um array.

```
const cookie = json['set-cookie'];
```